# How do you manage dependencies between automated UI tests?

Tags: automated-testing, test-design

I am currently helping out with the [TodoMVC](http://todomvc.com) project by adding automated tests. I have been 'exercising' my tests by trying them out on new submissions, such as [this one recently](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/pull/798#issuecomment-33368567). One problem I have discovered is that the test results often look worse than they actually are due to dependencies between tests. Because these are automated UI tests, if for example the process of adding items to the todo list has a small flaw, the knock on effect is that numerous other tests will fail indirectly, even if the function that are trying to test is actually correctly implemented.

I don't think it looks great to have 14 failures when there are actually only 3 underlying failures. It doesn't help people diagnose and solve these issues.

What might be better is that if a pre-requisite test fails subsequent tests are not executed.

In a general / conceptual sense, how do you manage dependencies between tests? Do you acknowledge these dependencies in any way?

Comment: Please search for questions about dependencies.

Comment: We automate our test using Specflow built on MSTest. We have test data set for every scenario placed in the background and we have methods placed in AfterScenario section (basically TearDown unit test method) to clean up the database once the scenario run regardless whether it is passed or failed. In this way we have absolutely independent tests and there are no dependencies between them.
In my opinion, dependencies between test cases will be a nightmare soon or later.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever possible,
instead of managing dependencies,
I work very hard
to eliminate them,
or at least reduce them.

Another high priority goal for me
is to *eliminate any technology that is not **directly** involved*
in the feature I'm testing.
Every additional element of technology
offers possibilities
for the tests to fail
*independent of whether the system implements the feature correctly*.

For through-the-UI tests,
I like to have each test use the GUI
*only for GUI feature the test is testing*.

Think of a test in three rough parts:

- Set up preconditions
- Invoke the feature being tested.
- Verify the results produced by the system.

If my test is testing that the feature can be invoked through the GUI,
then I'll go through the GUI to invoke the feature.
But I will *skip around the GUI*
to set up the preconditions
and verify the results.
I'll call some lower level API,
or stuff data into the database,
or something.

If my test is testing that the system displays
specific results in some specific way
through the GUI,
then I'll go through the GUI to verify the results.
But I will *skip around the GUI*
to set up the preconditions
and invoke the feature.

And if my test is not testing anything *specifically about the GUI,*
I will eliminate the GUI from the test altogether,
and make API calls into the system.

Further,
when I *am* testing GUI stuff,
I like to eliminate the system.
Instead, provide a mock system
that I can control directly
with my test code.

Then my test verifies that when the user fiddles with some widget,
the GUI makes the right API call.

Or it verifies that when the system gives a response,
the GUI displays it correctly
(to the limited extent that can be verified with automation).

I like to have very few
end-to-end automated tests.
Just enough to discover whether
the parts are wired together correctly.

For more complex things
like following data through the system,
have people do the tests.
People are much less sensitive to minor technology burps
that would cause an automated end-to-end test
to fail inadvertently.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two different possible situations when we talk about that sort of test dependencies. Let's say we have 2 tests A and B

1. If A and B depend on the same component/feature of your product and you know that if A fails, then, B can not success, then you should skip test B altogether. For example, a login/password page where A check that input forms for login and password are displayed and B test some set of inputs. In Robot Framework, I check [${PREV TEST STATUS}](http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/libraries/BuiltIn.html) at the beginning of execution of B and, if it is Failed, then I stop B (using "[fail](http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Fail)")
2. If B will fail because it uses the feature tested in A and this feature fails, but more in a workflow way. Then I will try to make B independent of this feature. For example, if A test "add item to list" and B test "remove item from list", then if the setup of B is "first add an item", then B will fail when A fails. What I would do is to add the item with a non-gui / more robust way (updating directly the "objects" that contains the list of items... whether it is a javascript object, a file or a database).

Answer (score 0):

The way I solve this is to ensure all the unit tests will revert back to the 'known' state regardless what happens. For example, I have a feature that manage subscription via web. In 'add' subscription tests, I always clear up the subscription data before the next test.

HTH, 
Chuan

Comment: Thanks - but this question is about UI tests. It is not an issue due to a failed 'tear down', it is because to test persistence, for example, a certain amount of functionality must work correctly already.